# Handle missing data when flattening nested array field in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

We need to flatten this into a standard 2D DataFrame:

```
arr = [
    [{ 'id': 3, 'abbr': 'ORL', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}, 
     { 'id': 5, 'abbr': 'ATL', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}],
    [{ 'id': 7, 'abbr': 'NYK', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}, 
     { 'id': 9, 'abbr': 'BOS', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}]
]
pd.DataFrame(data = {'name': ['nick', 'tom'], 'arr': arr })
```

Here's our code, which is working just fine for this dummy example

```
for i in range(len(mydf)):
    output_list = []
    for i in range(len(mydf)):
        team1 = mydf['arr'][i][0]
        team2 = mydf['arr'][i][1]
        zed = { 't1': team1['abbr'], 't2': team2['abbr'] }
        output_list.append(zed)

    output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_list)
    
final_df = pd.concat([mydf, output_df], axis=1)
final_df.pop('arr')
final_df

    name    t1  t2
0   nick    ORL ATL
1   tom     NYK BOS
```

Our source of data is not reliable and ma have missing values, and our code seems fraught with structural weaknesses. In particular, errors are thrown when either of these are the raw data (missing field, missing dict):

```
# missing dict
arr = [
    [{ 'id': 3, 'abbr': 'ORL', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}],
    [{ 'id': 7, 'abbr': 'NYK', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}, 
     { 'id': 9, 'abbr': 'BOS', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}]
]
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data = {'name': ['nick', 'tom'], 'arr': arr })

# missing "abbr" field
arr = [
    [{ 'id': 3, 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}, 
     { 'id': 5, 'abbr': 'ATL', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}],
    [{ 'id': 7, 'abbr': 'NYK', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}, 
     { 'id': 9, 'abbr': 'BOS', 'record': { 'win': 3, 'loss': 7 }}]
]
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data = {'name': ['nick', 'tom'], 'arr': arr })
```

Is it possible to (a) replace the for-loop with a more structurally sound approach (apply), and (b) handle the missing data concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that "abbr" key may not exist. You could account for that using `dict.get` method. If you replace:

```
zed = { 't1': team1['abbr'], 't2': team2['abbr'] }
```

with

```
zed = { 't1': team1.get('abbr', np.nan), 't2': team2.get('abbr', np.nan) }
```

it will work as expected.

An alternative approach that doesn't use explicit loop:

You could `explode` and `str.get` the `abbr` field; convert it to a list; build a DataFrame with it and `join` it back to `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'name': ['nick', 'tom'], 'arr': arr })
out = (df.join(pd.DataFrame((df['arr']
                             .explode()
                             .str.get('abbr')
                             .groupby(level=0)
                             .agg(list)
                             .tolist()), 
                           columns=['t1','t2'], index=df.index))
       .drop(columns='arr')
       .fillna(np.nan))
```

For the sample that works in your code:

```
name   t1   t2
0  nick  ORL  ATL
1   tom  NYK  BOS
```

For the first sample that doesn't work:

```
   name   t1   t2
0  nick  ORL  NaN
1   tom  NYK  BOS
```

For the second sample that doesn't work:

```
   name   t1   t2
0  nick  NaN  ATL
1   tom  NYK  BOS
```